# Making graph - run-time error 424 - Object required

Tags: excel, object, graph, vba

I am trying to make a graph using the following VBa code. But I am getting a `Run-time error 424 - Object required` at the row:

```
Set rngChtXVal = .Columns(1).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
```

What is going wrong?

```
    Sub MakeGraph()
    Dim myChtObj As ChartObject
    Dim rngChtData As Variant
    Dim rngChtXVal As Variant
    Dim iColumn As Long

    sel= Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(200, 2))
     rngChtData = sel

    ' define chart's X values
    With rngChtData
       Set rngChtXVal = .Columns(1).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With

    ' add the chart
    Set myChtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=250, Width:=425, Top:=10, Height:=240)
    With myChtObj.Chart

        ' make an XY chart
        .ChartType = xlLine

        ' remove extra series
        Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
            .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop

        ' add series from selected range, column by column
        For iColumn = 2 To rngChtData.Columns.Count
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Values = rngChtXVal.Offset(, iColumn - 1)
                .XValues = rngChtXVal
                .Name = rngChtData(1, iColumn)
            End With
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout If i put Set in front of it then i am getting the same error.

Comment: You need `Set` earlier: `Set rngChtData = sel`

Answer (score 0):

You've named rngChtData and rngChtXVal like `Range` objects, but you've declared them as `Variant`. While Variants can be Ranges, it makes debugging your code much harder. Use explicit variable types whenever possible. To resolve your issue, change your code like this:

```
Sub MakeGraph()
Dim myChtObj As ChartObject
Dim rngChtData As Range
Dim rngChtXVal As Range
Dim iColumn As Long

With Sheets("Data")
    Set rngChtData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(200, 2))
End With

' define chart's X values
With rngChtData
   Set rngChtXVal = .Columns(1).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
End With
```

Comment: I want to keep the range as an array because it will be an input from an other sub. So it will be changing for different graphs.

Comment: You're using the `Offset` method of the `Range` object, so you'll have to choose what you really want--a two-dimensional array or range object.

Comment: I want to make a graph from a array. Could you advise on how i can do that in vba?

Comment: You can build a chart with explicit values (e.g. not tied to a range), by setting the `.Values` property of the series object to an array. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197014%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for an example.